# Basic QT in C++ - Having trouble comprehending

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, signals-slots

I'm having trouble understanding how QT works. Can somebody show me an example, where you have a frame with a button named "button1" and when that button is pushed, do something, maybe a

```
cout << "hi";
```

I can't seem to understand how to setup the slot for a QPushButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 1):

Start here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/how-to-learn-qt.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at the examples in the Qt folder.

c:/qt/4.7.1/examples/